# Angular 2: passing object with nested object to child component

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I have nested object

```
data: {
  nestedData: {
    title: 'string'
  }
};
```

I pass this data to child component via property

```
<child-component [data]="data"></child-component>
```

Child component code:

```
import {Component, Input} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'cp-header',
  template: '<div>{{ data.nestedData.nestedData }}</div>',
  styleUrls: ['app/header/header.component.css']
})
export class ChildComponent {
  @Input() data;
}
```

Then when I try to access object property in template I got error;

Comment: is `child-compoennt` in your mark-up just a typo here? and what does you `Component` definition look like?

Comment: @james Just selector, templateUrl & styleUrls properties

Comment: How and where do you access it in the child?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using elvis operator in your HTML: `data?.nestedData?.title`.

You should also change `@Input data` to `@Input() data`.

Comment: I have added view in component decorator

Comment: Right, my bad, my eyes parsed it as an URL. Was using elvis operator of any help?

Comment: My bad, I fixed typo in @Input(). So if I access data in template just like that {{ data | json}} there is no error. But if I write like this {{ data.nestedData }} I have error `EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'nestedData' of undefined in [{{ data.nestedData?.title}}. Elvis operator doesn't help.

Comment: What about `data?.nestedData?.title`?

Comment: Using elvis in every property helped

Answer (score 0):

You can't access inputs in the constructor. They are set just before `ngOnInit` is called:

```
export class ChildComponent {
  @Input data;

  constructor() {
    console.log(this.data); // here it prints `null`
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.data); // here it prints the actual value
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not trying to access input data in constructor, I'm trying to access it in view

Comment: That's nice to know but you still don't show how. Then you probably need to use the safe-navigation operator. `{{data?.nestedData?.title}}` or `="data?.nestedData?.title"`